# composition vs data encapsulation

Tags: encapsulation, composition

If a class A is in composition relationship with class B , does it mean that the specific instance of B got via A should only be modifiable through class A not to break the data encapsulation of class A? Or, does composition imply only life-time bind, not the data encapsulation ?

```
class A
{
   B itsB;
   B* getB() {return &itsB);
}

void AnotherClass::anyOperation()
{
   itsA->getB()->function(); // is this legal ? 
}
```

Comment: It should be itsA.getB()->function() , if its C++ you are using.

Comment: it depends on if itsA is instantiated as a B itsB or, B* itsB = new B()

Comment: In the previous comment, I wrote B instead of A, by mistake. I meant if AnotherClass instantiated itsA as "A itsA", it would be "itsA." However, if it is instantiated as A* itsA = new A(), it would be "itsA->".

Answer (score 4):

Composition does not strictly specify the rules concerning whether a composed object should be allowed to be modified outside the composing class or not.

Encapsulation has to do with controlling access to the members defined in a class to outside world. In general ,fields of a class should not be directly accessible by outside code , if this tenet is followed , then the question of allowing it to be modifeid by outside code does not arise. Encapsulation and composition are not related in principle , so in your example , the fact that `B` is a composed into `A` itself does not dictate the rule that `itsB` should not be modifiable outside `A`.

However , you should think in terms of 1. Who owns the object `itsB` ? 2. Is it thread-safe to allow it to be modified outside `A` ? Is it breaking encapsulation ?

Comment: 1. Who owns the object itsB : The class A owns it, as the composition already implies that. The class A creates it, uses it, destroys it. I feel I miss something . 2. What is that about thread-safety? And lastly, you ask "is it breaking encapsulation?" although you stated previously that "encapsulation and composition are not related in principle". I am really confused more.

Comment: 1. right - so it should be managed by class A only. 2. When you allow objects cotained in another object to be modified outside the containing object - this usually causes great problems when multiple threads are involved - so I meant that you should carefully consider that aspect before you accept this design 3 - Here I mean - you should if the modification of field itsB may cause pre and post conditions to be violated ? This consideration is purely from encapsulation point of view - and composition does not dictate this check itself. Hope this helps ..

Comment: I know this is old but I don't agree with this. Exposing an object that is inside another object straight up breaks encapsulation. One would either need to duplicate functions of the inside object in the parent object OR only pass the child object to functions of the parent object to be worked on instead of storing it.

Answer (score 2):

If B has public setter functions, the only way in C++ to ensure that nobody retrieves A's B through `getB()` and changes its value is for `getB()` to return a constant reference. If it returned a constant pointer, that just ensures that you don't change the pointer; you can still change the values inside the B that the pointer points to.

Comment: hmm.. i think I was confused with the const pointer and const object. So, returning a constant pointer to object B inside A, anyone in association with that object may call its operations freely :) not only its const declared functions, as would be the case for const pointer to const data.. hmmm. I feel I got it..

Comment: One point to make it clear Vanessa... You said that "If B has public setter functions"  Did you mean class A has a method like setB(B* pB) or setB(B b), which changes the A's B ?

Comment: No, I meant if B has a function setMyField(int fieldValue) or some such, the only way to prevent people from getting A's B and calling setMyField is to make getB() return a const B&.

Comment: I want to be able to assign &itsB ( of class A) to some other associations in the system and let it be used freely, respecting data encapsulation principle at the same time. So, it is more confusing me when I see "returning const B&" at your last post and when I read "you can still change the values inside the B" at your previous post...

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you were trying to prevent other classes from retrieving itsB and modifying it. If you want to let them modify it, don't return a constant reference. A constant pointer will let them call B functions that modify B's fields, although not point it to a completely different B object. How much access you give via getB() really depends on whether and how much A is relying on itsB not to be changed outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

**To mention my problem with different words:**

The class A has mB and mC members , where A and B, A and C are in composition relationships.

B and C classes are in association relationship.

What would you say, if I want to link specific instance "mB" to specific instance "mC" (of class A), allowing them to communicate between themselves.

Would it mean to break the encapsulation provided by A for mB and mC ?

Comment: It depends on whether this inter object communication between two composed objects ( B and C ) in A will violate pre and post conditions expected by A's design or not. If it does violate , it breaks encapsulation, otherwise not.